# Left-recursion removal, to get the equivalent grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, left-recursion, pushdown-automaton

```
S → Y | 0Z
Y → Y1 | 1Z | 1Z 00
Z → 1Z | 0
```

I know the Y is left recursive but why is the Z not left recursive?

For Y i got

```
Y -> 1ZF | 1Z00
F -> 1F | e
```

Then factoring

```
Y -> 1ZX | 1ZX
F -> 1F | e
X -> F | 00F
```

Where 'e' is empty

Comment: `Z` is not left-recursive because the rule is `Z -> 1Z`, not `Z -> Z1`.

Comment: More corrently, Y will become Y -> 1ZF | 1Z00F while eliminating left recursion.